# Django app disappears from admin on page refresh

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm going through django 1.9 tutorial. I set up webserver, mysql, django 1.9 and I'm using default python 2.7.5. Just created new project and "polls" app. So my problem is the app is disappearing from admin page on page refresh with a 404 error threw. I recorded this on [video](https://youtu.be/UT7vChG3fJA) for clarity. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the video, it looks like you are using Apache to serve your website. That means you need to restart the server after updating your code, for example:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Note that it's not a good idea to use `DEBUG=True` on a publicly accessible server.

Comment: Thanks, it works as charm now. Just curious why don't they put this hint into tutorial. As for debug, I'll change the setting when I finish this project.

Comment: The tutorial assumes that you are using `runserver`, which automatically reloads, so I'm not sure where the best place to put that hint would be. I'm not sure whether the hint is in the docs somewhere else. If not, please open a ticket, even better include a patch for the docs.